# AJAX POST request working in POSTMAN but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, postman

I am trying to make a simple AJAX POST request. This request when executed in POSTMAN works fine. However, when I code it in jQuery and try to make the same request, I get

**No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 415.**

Now, I have to make a POST request and hence using JSONP as type in the request won't help. I do not have access to server code to modify it. My basic understanding is that if POSTMAN can execute it, then i should be able to do it as well

Comment: The URIs you are using in postman and chrome(I assume in an web application(may be ajax call)) are same, for sure?

Comment: not de same, postman works like a navigator, and you are accesing by javascript code, from localhost domain ( or any)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón. Can i do anything about this ?

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL, Yes the URIs are same. However, when checked in fiddler the headers look different.

Comment: yes you can use your back of your localhost to call it from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the status code is self explanatory.
`415` it's returned from the server when you sent an unsupported content type (e.g. an xml). double check the type of data you're passing to the post request in your code.

> 415 UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE The origin server is refusing to service
>   the request because the payload is in a format not supported by this
>   method on the target resource.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated
>   Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the
>   data directly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Comment: Astute observation. Thanks a bunch, buddy

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't automatically work in the browser if it works in Postman. You can still get **CORS**-errors.

You might also check the content type, you are getting **HTTP STATUS 415** which is [UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE](https://httpstatuses.com/415)
. This might be your problem, the media type differs in the request.

I also noticed you are serving from `file://`, maybe you should host it so you are serving your site from `localhost` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue is you are running your page from a file directly(**May be just double clicking on the file in windows**) rather using an server.

So first of all access the page via server, install any server like **apache**, and access the page via

```
http://localhost/pagename
```