# POST request doesn't get response from server in chrome but work in postman

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'am making a POST request to spring boot endpoint and wanna get data return from server.With testing my API in Postman,it works good.but when testing it in 
chrome,it doesn't even get a response and chrome NETWORK bar even did't have record.
so code is simple,I can't find any problem,RestController

```
 @PostMapping("/signup")
    public User signup(@RequestBody ModelUser user){
          //fetch data from DTO and craft a user
          User userData=user.adapter();
          //...code here omit for sake of brevity

          return userData;
    }
```

it indeed get data from ajax,when I use logger(slf4j) to debug.
and ajax:

```
  $("#sign-up").submit(function () {
           var userInfo={}
           userInfo["phone"]=$("#phone").val()
           userInfo["password"]=$("#password").val()
           $.ajax({
               //ajax successful send to spring boot endpoint
               type:"POST",
               contentType:"application/json",
               url:"http://localhost:8080/signup",
               data:JSON.stringify(userInfo)
           }).then(
               function(){
                  //this doesn't print in console
                  console.log("Hello Callback is executed")
               }
           )
       })
```

weird as it is,I never encounter this when I use GET request,since ajax callback is successfully called when I use GET to test a GetMapping endpoint.

oh,with lots of similar questions

- [AJAX POST request working in POSTMAN but not in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469148/ajax-post-request-working-in-postman-but-not-in-chrome)
- [Angular 4 POST call to php API fails, but GET request work and POST requests work from Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844178/angular-4-post-call-to-php-api-fails-but-get-request-work-and-post-requests-wor)
- [POST response arrives in Postman, but not via Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355792/post-response-arrives-in-postman-but-not-via-ajax)

I don't get any response status code in chrome and completely not involved CORS in question

Comment: @user7294900 what do you mean?

Comment: whats the purpose of the object your returning in your controller and the console log within the then callback ? Try using @ResponseBody instead.

Comment: @ThivankaW oh,this endpoint is in a class annotated with `RestController`,and I wanna get response data from server and redirect page in front end

Comment: The data your returning is basically a java object , so you want to return a java object to the frontend page ? Maybe you want this java object in json format ? I dont see a success callback in your ajax , you need to implement it first to extract the response

Comment: @ThivankaW yes,I wanna JSON format.the `then`  callback will get called no matter fail or success as long as response is returned by backend.but the point is my ajax didn't get response from server,let alone data returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am sorry for my poor front end skill,the main reason is that I don't understand Javascript event.

```
$("#sign-up").submit(function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var user={};
    user["phone"]="187308";
    user["name"]="icywater";
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        contentType:'application/json',
        data:JSON.stringify(user),
        url:"http://localhost:8080/test"

    }).done(function(data){
        console.log("Hello Callback is executed");
        console.log(data)
    });
});
```

here when I click submit It actually already submit the form and don't wait ajax code to be executed,so I should use `e.preventDefault()`to suppress default behavior.It's nothing 
related about POST or postman ,it is about the form submit default behavior,ahh,Oolong event.

I got it when I found [this page](https://javascript.info/forms-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a consumes and produces media type of Json in the Java

```
@PostMapping(path="/signup", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

And explicitly set the Accept header in the javascript

```
   $.ajax({
           //ajax successful send to spring boot endpoint
           type:"POST",
           headers: {Accept : "application/json"},
           contentType:"application/json",
           url:"http://localhost:8080/signup",
           data:JSON.stringify(userInfo)
       })
```

Comment: It doesn't work,I guess since spring boot consumes and produces JSON by default,and ajax actually can intelligently identify content format in terms of ajax API,so it doesn't make any difference